# read a file and determine a String

Tags: java, arrays, loops, text-files, file-handling

assume that my text file consist this:

```
NOT VOTED/1/gello/18
NOT VOTED/2/tara/24
```

arrangements is like `status if user already voted or not/voter's number/name/age` i divided the information line into array so it is like this

`info[0]=status/info[1]=voters number/info[2]=name/info[3]=age`

here is the function of my program:

1. read a file
2. let the user enter a voters number
3. if voters number matches info[1], proceed to step 3
4. while info[0] contains "VOTED" it will get an error message that that voter's number already voted and enter another voters number. if false it will proceed to the voting process
5. now info[0] will changed in to "VOTED"

here is my code:

```
        File original = new File("C:\\voters.txt");//open the original file     
        File temporary = new File("C:\\tempvoters.txt");//create temporary file

        BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(original));//read the file
        PrintWriter outfile = new PrintWriter(new PrintWriter(temporary));//write the data

        vNum=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter voters number: ");
        String line=null;
        String something="VOTED";
        while((line=infile.readLine())!=null){

            String [] info=line.split("/");
            if(info[1].matches(vNum)){

                while(info[0].matches(something)) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Voter already voted or Voter not registered. Please try again");
                    vNum=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter voters number: ");
                }

                President();
                Vice_President();
                info[0]="VOTED";
                all=info[0]+"/"+info[1]+"/"+info[2]+"/"+info[3]+"/"+info[4]+"/"+info[5]+"/"+info[6]+"/"+info[7]+"/"+info[8]+"/"+info[9]+"/"+info[10]+"/"+info[11]+"/"+info[12];
                outfile.println(all);
                outfile.flush();
            }
            else{
                outfile.println(line);
                outfile.flush();
            }


        }

        infile.close();
        outfile.close();

        original.delete();//delete the original file
        temporary.renameTo(original);//rename the temporary file to original file
```

now this happens in the code that i made:

assume i enter `1` as voters number. and because the info[0] still contains "NOT VOTED", it will proceed to voting process and after that the element of info[0] now contains "VOTED". now after that process it will go back to main menu. now when i go back entering another voters number again, i tried entering `1` again to see if it will appear the error message. it did. so i entered the other voter's number again which is `2` and its info[0] still contains "NOT VOTED" BUT the error message will still appear!! i am really stuck with that process and i don't know what to do with that anymore because i am really clueless what is wrong. to think the functions in this method of my program are just the same with the other methods that i had. please please please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> while(info[0].matches(something))

It looks to me as though you're not breaking out of this while loop, since info[0] will always be true since variable "something" isn't being changed. What I would suggest is this:

> {
>       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Voter already voted or Voter not     registered. Please try again");
>       vNum=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter voters number: ");
>       something = "NOT VOTED";  //This will break the loop
>   }

Comment: i tried changing it into info[0].matches("VOTED") but it is still the same :/ can you suggest on how should i do it?

Comment: Edited my post to include a suggestion.

Comment: oh it already works!!!!!!! but there is still a problem like after the voting process the error message will appear again and makes me enter a voters number again

Comment: Try moving the line String something="VOTED"; just below the first while loop, above where you split the line into the array.